# Android: Dagger 2 and constructor injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I'm new to dagger and my constructor/method injection doesn't seem to work.
Doesn't work meaning the injected fields are still requested.

This is my code:

```
@Module
public class AppContextModule {

    private final Context appContext;

    public AppContextModule(Context appContext) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Context getAppContext() {
        return appContext;
    }

}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppContextModule.class})
public interface MyComponent {

    void inject(ActivitiesLifeCycleListener obj);

    void inject(WebViewManager obj);

    Context context();

}

public final class MyClass {

    private final WeakReference<Context> mAppContext;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(Context context)  {
        this.mAppContext = context
    }

}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyClass my = new MyClass(); // The IDE requests context!

    }

}
```

"MyClass" still requires "Context" although I used the "@Inject" annotation above the constructor.
What am I missing?

Do I even need to expose my Context?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of @inject if you are going to create instance ` MyClass my = new MyClass();` like this?

Answer (score 10):

Well...you declare your constructor

```
public MyClass(Context context)  {
    this.mAppContext = context
}
```

And then call it without any parameters

```
MyClass my = new MyClass(); // The IDE requests context!
```

**Why** do you think this should work? This is plain java, no dagger involved, and you are trying to create some new object without supplying the arguments needed.

---

Dagger is no magic that changes how java works. To use constructor injection you have to actually use Dagger to inject your fields.

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    MyClass mMyClass; // mark field for injection

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // todo ... create component

        component.inject(this); // inject fields
    }

}
```

Given that you provide a `Context` somewhere (you'll get a `Context must be provided...` compile error if it is not) dagger will then inject your activity with `MyClass` by **calling** `inject`—no magic. The `inject` method will assign the object to your field.

---

Constructor injection only means that you don't have to use a module and include a method to provide the object. It does not just magically create objects out of thin air or change the way constructors work.

Comment: could you help me on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/43308649/6596724 , Thanks

Comment: Would be great if you had shown how to make a component for class which is not a module.