# android getting NULL error on inject DI into class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I can make DI from some class to use in application such as `Retrofit`, `Picasso`.
they can work fine when i use them on Activity but when i try to use some DI on other class i get NULL, for exmple this code work fine

```
public class ActivityRegister extends BaseActivities {

    @Inject
    GithubService githubService;

    @Inject
    JobManager jobManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        repositoryCall = githubService.getAllRepositories();
        ...
}

private void getRepositories() {
    repositoryCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
            List<GithubRepo> repoList = new ArrayList<>();
            repoList.addAll(response.body());
            Log.e("JOB ", "OK");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("JOB ", "NO!!");
        }
    });
}
```

for `GithubService` i get created instance successfull, not i'm trying to use that into `GetLatestRepositories`, but i get `NULL`, how can i define correctly that to injecting into class?

```
public class GetLatestRepositories extends Job {
    @Inject
    GithubService githubService;

    private Call<List<GithubRepo>> repositoryCall;

    public GetLatestRepositories() {
        super(new Params(Priority.MID).requireNetwork().persist());
        repositoryCall = githubService.getAllRepositories();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        repositoryCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
                List<GithubRepo> repoList = new ArrayList<>();
                repoList.addAll(response.body());
                Log.e("JOB ", "OK");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("JOB ", "NO!!");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancel(int cancelReason, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(@NonNull Throwable throwable, int runCount, int maxRunCount) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ActivityRegisterComponent` component class:

```
@ActivityRegisterScope
@Component(modules = ActivityRegisterModule.class, dependencies = GithubApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ActivityRegisterComponent {

    void injectActivityRegister(ActivityRegister homeActivity);
}
```

`GithubApplicationComponent`:

```
@GithubApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {GithubServiceModule.class, PicassoModule.class, JobManagerModule.class, ActivityModule.class})
public interface GithubApplicationComponent {

    Picasso getPicasso();

    GithubService getGithubService();

    JobManager getJobManager();
}
```

Application class:

```
public class Alachiq extends Application {

    ...
    public static  Alachiq                    alachiq;
    public static  String                     packageName;
    public static  Resources                  resources;

    private static Context                    context;

    private        GithubService              githubService;
    private        Picasso                    picasso;
    private        GithubApplicationComponent component;
    private        JobManager                 jobManager;
    private static Alachiq                    instance;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //@formatter:off
            resources   = this.getResources();
            context     = getApplicationContext();
            packageName = getPackageName();
        //@formatter:on


        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

        component = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .build();

        githubService = component.getGithubService();
        picasso = component.getPicasso();
        jobManager = component.getJobManager();
    }

    public GithubApplicationComponent component() {
        return component;
    }

    public static Alachiq get(Activity activity) {
        return (Alachiq) activity.getApplication();
    }

    public static Alachiq getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

and ActivityRegister `onCreate`:

```
ApplicationComponent component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .githubApplicationComponent(Alachiq.get(this).component())
                .build();
```

`GithubService` class:

```
public interface GithubService {

    @GET("users/{username}/repos")
    Call<List<GithubRepo>> getReposForUser(@Path("username") String username);

    @GET("repositories")
    Call<List<GithubRepo>> getAllRepositories();

    @GET("users/{username}")
    Call<GithubUser> getUser(@Path("username") String username);
}
```

Comment: are you implying you get null pointer at this line: " repositoryCall = githubService.getAllRepositories();" ?

Comment: Where are you calling inject?  Activities and Services are created by the Android framework so they need to be injected manually.

Comment: @ScottS yes sir i get null for `githubService` on this file `GetLatestRepositories`

Comment: @GabeSechan i'm calling inject in `GetLatestRepositories` class  as  `@Inject    GithubService githubService;`

Comment: That isn't calling inject. For items created by the framework (activities, services, views, etc) you must call the inject function on the controller you instantiated passing in the service/activity/view as a parameter

Comment: @GabeSechan controller? i dont understand me, could you tell me which file is your mean?

Comment: Wrong terminology, I appologize.  I meant component.  Your component should have an inject function for every type it wants to inject.  You must manually call that function for any object created by the framework, in order to inject that object.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm so sorry sir, but i dont know which file must be edited, i have main component as `GithubApplicationComponent` which its contain is  on my post, and i define `GithubService` into that

Comment: @GabeSechan i must have other component like with `ActivityRegisterComponent`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141291/discussion-between-tux-world-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: have you actually added this line on your appication's onCreate()?"myComponent= DaggerMyComponent.builder().computerModule(new ComputerModule()).build();" and then created a getter to obtain the component reference?

Comment: post your application class.

Comment: @ScottS my post updated with Application class and ActivityRegister `onCreate` method

Comment: Also, show us the GithubService class implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141296/discussion-between-scotts-and-tux-world).

Comment: Did you call injectActivityRegister in `ActivityRegister`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can even use the object from GithubService class you need to do the following:

```
 myComponent= DaggerMyComponent.builder().computerModule(new ComputerModule()).build();//replace accordingly.
```

In your case you will have to do something like:

```
githubService = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder().nameofYourModule(new NameOfTheClass()).build);
```

Now you can use the githubService object:

```
repositoryCall = githubService.getAllRepositories();
```

This is a type of design pattern called creational.

Comment: use `githubService = GithubApplicationComponent.builder().nameofYourModule(new NameOfTheClass()).build);` in `GetLatestRepositories` class ?

Comment: i pasted `GithubService` class into my post

Comment: No, in your application class.

Comment: It has to be in your application class.  Within onCreate()

Comment: its `DaggerGithubApplicationComponent`, it seems your mean is not correct, because i get error

Comment: Yes, you need to add prefix "Dagger": as follow githubService = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder().nameofYourModule(new NameOfTheClass()).build);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141298/discussion-between-tux-world-and-scotts).

Comment: just change following line: "GithubService githubService;" with GitHubApplicationComponent gitHubApplicationComponent; and replace "githubService = DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder().." with gitHubApplicationComponent = "DaggerGithubApplicationComponent.builder().."

Comment: `GetLatestRepositories` extends from `Job` and its used into `ActivityRegister`. In that I want to inject GithubService which I get null. Please review my post. Thanks

Comment: go to chat on link